# What's the best way to deal with circular object-owning references in a one/many-to-many C++ class associations?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, aggregation, circular-reference

Good day. I am facing a programming design task and am struggling with choosing the best approach for implementation due to lack of experience. I'd be glad to hear which practices, paradigms, or patterns are applicable to this case.

#### Problem Setting

You need to code, in *C++98 standard*, a `Worker` class that can own abstract `Tool`s. `Tool`s can exist on their own, hence can be equipped and unequipped by workers; tools can't have more than one worker owner.

However, what makes this trickier is the fact lifetimes of these objects need to be managed accordingly:

- If a `Tool` is destroyed, it needs to get unequipped, since holding a pointer to a destroyed tool can lead to undefined behavior.
- Similarly, if `Worker` is destroyed, the `Tool` should be disowned.
- If a `Tool` is already given to a `Worker`, giving it to another `Worker` does remove the `Tool` from the original worker.

On top of that, suppose there's a class called `Workshop`. Workshops must accept only workers who have an available tool of a certain pre-determined type (I decided to make `Workshop` a template for a `Tool` subtype).

If a workshop enrolls a worker, a random available tool of correct type gets associated with it and becomes unavailable to other enrollments. Again,

- If a `Worker` is destroyed, they leave the workshop.
- If a `Tool` that a `Worker` is using in a `Workshop` gets destroyed or assigned to another worker, the `Worker` leaves the Workshop.

#### Questions

What is the best approach to this type of relationship?

Currently, in order to implement the tool disowning upon destruction, I store `Tool` pointers inside workers, and a `Worker` pointer inside `Tool`s. `~Tool()` calls a `Worker` method that unequips it. However, since I want to make it possible to destroy the relationship from both classes, say, have a `Tool::unset_owner()` and `Worker::unequip(Tool*)`, both of them keep calling each other, resulting sometimes in infinite loops.

To add the `Workshop` support, I decided to create a `WorkshopBase` to hide its `ToolType` template, and hold an `std::map<Tool*, WorkshopBase*>` in `Worker` to register tools and workshops. But, it further results in chains of calling double-sided methods that attempt to remove/insert pointers from each other.

However, I feel like I'm missing something essential and am violating some best practices for such one-to-many + many-to-many relationships. So my question is:

- How to avoid coupling in this case as much as possible?
- I've seen many [posts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references) that claim this is a bad practice. I wonder if there's a design pattern to address this? Do you think an event system with management classes would be a better fit?
- All in all, how to achieve my desired result gracefully?

**Reminder**: I'm looking for a C++98 solution. However, I would prefer to have answers with solutions with newer standards, with `*_ptr<>` classes usage, maybe, as a footnote.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI pls don't be harsh on the C++98 standard... it's enforced in my programming school as "the newer standards complicate things" and "C++98 is only used as a tool to learn about OOP" so the new features are "redundant"

Comment: But it is 25 years old, and the rest of us have forgotten how it worked (or not worked).

Comment: The problem statement keeps saying "if a `Worker` is destroyed", "if a `Tool` is destroyed". Who is doing this destroying? Who decides when a particular worker or a particular tool should be destroyed? *That* entity would have owning pointers to tools and workers, and can enforce business rules. That entity could also keep track of which tools are associated with which workers; or tools and workers could have non-owning pointers to each other to reflect the associations, and the "master" entity would manipulate them to reflect current state of the world.

Comment: @Mampac *However, I would prefer to have answers with solutions with newer standards* -- Let's ask you -- what in C++11 going forward do you see that would make your task easier?  Mentioning that you can only use C++98 gives the impression there is something in C++11 that "works" but doesn't exist in C++98.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the problem statement was completely vague. there wasn't a requirement for a manager entity, but it doesn't mean it's forbidden. I was hoping my post would convey that the solution is free to introduce any new classes as it sees fit

Comment: In addition to higher-level methods like `Worker::unequip(Tool*)`, add lower-level methods like `Worker::disconnect(Tool*)` and `Tool::disconnect(Worker*)`. The lower-level methods would not call back through the passed-in pointer; they should assume that the object behind it is being destroyed and shouldn't be touched. Higher-level methods then can be implemented in terms of lower-level ones, orchestrating the interaction. Destructors would call `disconnect` on the associated object, if any.

Comment: If you are concerned about external code breaking invariants by calling low-level methods directly, make them private and make the associated classes friends of each other.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I wonder if you could post a simple example of method prototypes and possible implementation? so the workflow of connect/disconnect methods could be seen?

Answer (score 0):

The object pool pattern is a software creational design pattern that uses a set of initialized objects kept ready to use – a "pool" – rather than allocating and destroying them on demand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).